# Ionic Cordova platform add ios fails with Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, openssl, cocoapods, rbenv

I haven't been able to get this openSSL issue sorted trying to add iOS platform to an Ionic app. I've tried updating with Brew, reinstalling openSSL. I've tried to update Cocoa Pods but get the same error. I've updated Ionic and Cordova, updated some of the plugins. Still same error. Below is the stacktrace of the error

```
Running `pod install` (to install plugins)
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googlemaps': undefined
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: "/Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)\n" +
  '  Referenced from: /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle\n' +
  '  Reason: image not found - /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle\n' +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:76:in `const_get'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in classes'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:75:in `each'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:75:in `inject'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:75:in `block in classes'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:72:in `map'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:72:in `classes'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:86:in `extend_classes!'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:89:in `block in <module:Error>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:67:in `each'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:67:in `<module:Error>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:22:in `<module:REST>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest/error.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nap-1.1.0/lib/rest.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:74:in `<module:Pod>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/pod:23:in `load'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Users/billbolte/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'\n"
    at /Users/billbolte/Documents/Projects/customer-portal/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add ios@5.1.1 --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

below is my Ionic Info if needed

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.12.1) : 0.9.0
   native-run                             : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 6.1.3
   NodeJS     : v13.13.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.13.0_1/bin/node)
   npm        : 5.10.0
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.4.1 Build version 11E503a
```

Anyone have any ideas on what needs updated, fixed, removed, etc? I'm assuming this is a Cocoa Pods thing since running "pod env" produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In short, I had to update my current Ruby version to 2.7.1, make that the global version and then update Cocoapods. Then I was able to get by this error.